# Digma U-100H: внешний USB ТВ-тюнер

Tags: тв-тюнер, usb

Доброго времени суток! Как подключить внешний USB ТВ-тюнер Digma U-100H. Для Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В линуксах с тв-тюнерами большой напряг. Не хотят производители делать для них драйвера, и спецификации не открывают. Поэтому если драйвер сразу не установился, а на сайте производителя его нет, то придется от него отказаться под линуксом.